# Is the bundle class immutable and safe to reuse in firebase analytics?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

The [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/events) for firebase events indicate you should create a new bundle each time you want to log an event:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_ID, id);
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME, name);
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.CONTENT_TYPE, "image");
mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SELECT_CONTENT, bundle);
```

In cases where the same bundle data is logged multiple times, is it safe just to create the bundle once and hold on to it:

```
// Do this once in the constructor
bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_ID, id);
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME, name);
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.CONTENT_TYPE, "image");

// Reuse the bundle to log multiple events
mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SELECT_CONTENT, bundle);
mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SELECT_CONTENT, bundle);
```

Comment: Bundles are very much _not_ immutable. But where in the docs does it say that you should create a new bundle each time? It just shows an example of logging a single event, so obviously it needs to create a new bundle there. It would be bad API design if the passed-in bundle would silently be modified, so I think it should be safe to reuse it. The [API docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics#logEvent(java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle)) also don't prohibit reuse.

Comment: Yes without reusing Bundle there would be lot of events and params stuffed in one Bundle eventually leading to crash.